# how do you make it so the Android keyboard doesnt open up when the user opens up my app?

Tags: android, keyboard

can you make it so when you open up the app the on screen keyboard wont open up untill you click on one of the editText's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to hide the virtual keyboard, you can use the [InputMethodManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html) like this (you can put it in the `onCreate()`method of your landing activity) :

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in onCreate method of your activity:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

It did the trick for me :)

Answer (score 0):

in AndroidManifest.xml set android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"

Answer (score 0):

it is up to your requirement. For suppose if you want to hide the keyboard every time the user opens your activity, then you can add 
`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"` in your android manifest for your activity. If you want it dynamically then you can make change whenever event to close the keyboard occurs using

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Use [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) as reference whenever you want